# Magento 1.8.1 add custom attribute to product

Tags: php, magento-1.8

I'm web developer, but new in magento environment.

This shop has products with custom attributes. The sync of products between magento and ERP, is made by a webservice. That sync, puts into product, a field named "created_at".

I need, that fiels appears at catalog, is sort select and at the same time, this field must appear at magento dashboard, **System > Configuration > Catalog > Frontend > Product Listing Sort by**.

How can i do this?